# gbXML file generation time

Tags: revit-api, ifc, bim, gbxml

I am trying to generate the gbXML file using solar computer plugin GBIS. However it has updated to 15% only in more than one hour. Is it normal for gbXML file to generate or export. For more information, the Revit model is 6 storey building with around 270-280 MEP Rooms.

Comment: I suggest posting your question on https://unmethours.com/questions/ which is dedicated to building modelling. I don't think this question is about programming, which is what Stack Overflow is used for.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.